# C2DM handle registration properly

Tags: android, registration, android-c2dm

I want to use C2DM in my android application. I am using code schemas shown in official tutorials.  Everything seems to work fine, but I have problem with handling registration properly.
There are 2 methods in C2DMMessaging class which I have to use: firstly register() and next getRegistrationID(). If I use them sequentially, I get null form the getRegistrationID(). The problem is registration is asynchronous. In my application in the beginning I need to know the regidtrationId, I can start the rest of the app only after I get it.
I tried to do some synchronization using monitors (i.e. wait() in register method and notify() in C2DMReceiver.onRegistered()), but it didn't work (the code of onRegistered() hasn't been reached, after calling wait() in register()).
In other words what I need is making registration synchronous, so I could continue, only after I get registrationId. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are following below guidelines:

1. To develop and test on the Android Emulator, you need to download the Android 2.2 version of the Google APIs Add-On into your SDK.
2. Make sure you set `android:minSdkVersion="8"` in the manifest.
3. Make sure you have at least one Google account synced on your emulator or device.

Comment: I don't see the connection.. Read my question carefully. But yes, all the things you 're asking about are OK. As I've written, the communication is working - I just want to handle it in a specific way.